# Python Sockets Address already in use error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I'll get webcam frame from RPi and I'll send it to my PC. Then, I'll send random number from the PC to the RPi. I need to do it in the same code (I will make a few changes on the image and print the information on the screen I connect to the RPI.). But when I tried to run code, the program returns this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flood/Desktop/server.py", line 32, in <module>
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Server.py :

```
import io
import cv2
import socket
import struct
import time
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

ip = str(input('Enter IP address: '))
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    cl_socket = socket.socket()
    cl_socket.connect((ip, 8000))
    cl_connection = cl_socket.makefile('wb')
    stream = io.BytesIO()
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
    frame.save(stream, format="JPEG")
    stream.seek(0)
    image_bytes = stream.read()
    cl_connection.write(struct.pack('<L', len(image_bytes))) 
    cl_connection.flush()
    stream.seek(0)
    cl_connection.write(stream.read())
    stream.seek(0)
    stream.truncate() 
    cl_connection.close()
    cl_socket.close()

    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8001))
    server_socket.listen(0)
    server_connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rwb')
    
    while True:
        message = server_connection.readline()
        if message:
            print(message)
            break
```

Client.py :

```
import cv2
import io
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import random

while True:
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8001))
    server_socket.listen(0)
    server_connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
    
    image_len = struct.unpack('<L', server_connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
    if not image_len:
        break
    image_stream = io.BytesIO()
    image_stream.write(server_connection.read(image_len))
    image_stream.seek(0)
    image = Image.open(image_stream).convert('RGB')
    image = np.array(image)
    cv2.imshow('Image', cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
    cv2.waitKey(1)

    server_connection.close()
    server_socket.close()

    new_socket = socket.socket()
    new_socket.connect(('192.168.1.109', 8000))
    new_connection = new_socket.makefile('rwb')
    r = random.randint(0, 100)
    new_connection.write(str(r).encode())
    new_connection.flush()

    new_connection.close()
    new_socket.close()
```

Comment: Why are you starting a server on the same port in your client? That's the problem if these are being run on the same machine.

Comment: The code you show does not fit the error. There is no bind/listen on port 8000 in your code, only on port 8001. And it is not really clear for me what you are trying to do in the first place. It looks like you are trying to do a bidirectional connection by having each side being both client and server. But, there is no need to this since sockets can actually be bidirectional already.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I know sockets can be bidirectional, but when I try this, the program gives an error again. The message sent from the first machine is received, but the message sent from the second machine is not received and a problem occurs in the program.

Comment: @EmirÜnalan: *"... but when I try this, the program gives an error again. ..."* - the code for using a single socket with bi-directional communication should look significantly different from what you show in your question. It is impossible to give any advice about this code, since too much of it is unknown.